# react reset button clear text input area, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are my buttons, I've been trying to clear out all the text input, with the last one there, `ButtonNumber number="R"`. My idea was that I could just call the `constructor()` again from that button- and that this would reset my state, and essentially perform the task of a reset button- however, this is not the case, you can see it at the end there:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ButtonNumber from './ButtonNumber.js'

export default class ButtonNumberContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="numbers">
        <div className="btn-number-container">
          <ButtonNumber number="0" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="1" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="2" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="3" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="4" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="5" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="6" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="7" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="8" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="9" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="R" addLogicToEquation={this.props.constructor()} ></ButtonNumber>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The app front end looks like this:

[image]

There's some code here that assigns functions to the buttons- maybe I'll need to define some kind of a "clear" function and call it from somewhere like here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ButtonEquation extends Component {
  render() {
    const { equation, addLogicToEquation, evalEquation } = this.props
    const equationClass = "btn btn-equation-" + equation

    return (
      <button className={equationClass} onClick={() => {evalEquation ? evalEquation() : addLogicToEquation(equation)}}>
        {equation}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

The full code base [lives here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc).

---

**EDIT**

This file:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ButtonNumber from './ButtonNumber.js'

export default class ButtonNumberContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="numbers">
        <div className="btn-number-container">
          <ButtonNumber number="0" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="1" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="2" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="3" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="4" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="5" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="6" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="7" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="8" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="9" addLogicToEquation={this.props.addLogicToEquation} ></ButtonNumber>
          <ButtonNumber number="R" clearTheForm={this.props.clearTheForm} ></ButtonNumber>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also this one:

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

    export default class ButtonNumber extends Component {
      render() {
        const { number, addLogicToEquation, evalEquation, clearTheForm } = this.props
        const numberClass = " btn btn-number-" + number

        return (
          //<button className={numberClass} onClick={() => {addLogicToEquation(number)}}>
          <button className={numberClass} onClick={() => {clearTheForm ? clearTheForm() : addLogicToEquation(number)}}>
            {number}
          </button>
        )
      }
    }
```

In the main logic of the application, tried to reset the state:

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          equation: 0,
        }

        this.addLogicToEquation = this.addLogicToEquation.bind(this)
        this.evalEquation = this.evalEquation.bind(this)
      }

clearTheForm(){
    this.state = {
    equation: 0,
  }
}
```

That's what the call to that function was about.

Comment: The location of your number rendering needs a function to clear itself. But you aren't going to use it in that component. You make it to pass it down to the child that is supposed to clear the inputs. Remember to `bind` that function when you pass it. If you need more help than that, just tell me.

Comment: I think I get what you mean- I've been trying it out in the edit of the OP, those two files relating to the buttons- but I keep getting an error on that conditional statement, i.e. `<button className={numberClass} onClick={() => {clearTheForm ? clearTheForm() : addLogicToEquation(number)}}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function to clear rendered numbers, in your `App`

```
clearTheForm() {
  this.setState({equation: "0"})
}
```

In `ButtonNumberContainer`, remember to `bind`

```
<ButtonNumber number="R" clearTheForm={this.props.clearTheForm.bind(this)} ></ButtonNumber>
```

In `ButtonNumber`, your functions exist in `this.props`.

```
<button className={numberClass} onClick={() => {this.props.clearTheForm ? this.props.clearTheForm() : this.props.addLogicToEquation(number)}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you need is `setState` function. To update the `state` and rerun the `render` function when `clearTheForm`. Like this.

```
clearTheForm(){
    this.setState({
      equation: 0
    });
}
```

Hope this help.

**EDIT**
You also need to send `clearTheForm` method as a prop to `ButtonNumberContainer`.
Like this.

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
          equation: 0,
        }

        this.addLogicToEquation = this.addLogicToEquation.bind(this)
        this.evalEquation = this.evalEquation.bind(this)
        this.clearTheForm = this.clearTheForm.bind(this)
      }

      clearTheForm(){
          this.setState({
            equation: 0
          });
      }

      addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
          ...
      }

      evalEquation() {
          ...
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Result text={this.state.equation}/>
            <ButtonNumberContainer addLogicToEquation={this.addLogicToEquation} clearTheForm={this.clearTheForm} />
            <ButtonEquationContainer addLogicToEquation={this.addLogicToEquation}
                                     evalEquation={this.evalEquation}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: yeah - but where and how to call that?

Comment: You can pass the `clearTheForm` function as props to `ButtonNumberContainer` like you passing `addLogicToEquation` function.
See my edited answer.